# Consume SOAP web service in Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap

I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service, (from SharePoint 2010 if it makes a difference). I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3. What is the best way to do this? I've read some stuff mentioning Savon http://savonrb.com/ but that is was too new and buggy. Is it still the best solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Savon successfully to interact with the Bullhorn Staffing SOAP based service about six months ago.  I didn't have any problems with the Savon Gem, all my headaches came from inconsistencies with the service.

My interactions with their service was limited to getting data (simple) and pushing data, which could include a resume file (more complex).  I didn't have to look much further than the Savon doc to figure everything out, which I thought was simple to understand and easy to apply to my particular set of problems.

TLDR; 1 vote for Savon despite what you may have heard.

Comment: i've also used savon, though with 1.8.7. Never had many issues with it that weren't really issues with SOAP in general.

Answer (score 2):

I used savon to interact with Jira SOAP API and it worked fine.